# abstraction R. Variable Assignment

Tags: r

I want to save based on a variable.

`t="Cis"`
`d="1083"`

For this run, I had to use the following to create my named dataset based on these assigned variables.

`assign(paste0(t,"_",d,"_","tcpl.pod"), data.frame(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5))`

This worked and created my dataframe with name = `Cis_1083_tcpl.pod` This is important to me, because I will want to loop through different values for `t` and `d`.

Question 1:  I always hear "AVOID USING ASSIGN!"  Is there a better way of achieving the above?

Question 2:  I want to save that object and still refer to it based on the coding as follows:

`save(paste0(t,"_",d,"_","tcpl.pod"), file = paste0(t,"_",d,"tcpl.pod.RData"))`

This gives error that the `'paste0(t,"_",d,"tcpl.pod.RData"))'` not found.

How do I refer to the first paste construction appropriately in R?

P.S. 
`save(get(paste0(t,"_",d,"_","tcpl.pod")), file = paste0(t,"_",d,"tcpl.pod.RData"))` returns the same error.

Comment: Is there a better way? Use a [list of data frames instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17499013/903061). No `assign` needed, and it's easy to use the results.

Comment: For the save part, you'll probably need to use something like `save(get(paste0(t,"_",d,"_","tcpl.pod")), file = paste0(t,"_",d,"tcpl.pod.RData"))`

Comment: And `get` is what you want if you stick with the `assign(paste())` idiom - marking as dupe.

Comment: @MattJewett I had tried get. It does not work. Same error.

Comment: You should also look at `?save`, to use character strings with `save` use the `list` argument: `save(list = paste0(t,"_",d,"_","tcpl.pod"), file = paste0(t,"_",d,"tcpl.pod.RData"))`

Comment: @Gregor Can you please provide a link to the question this is a duplicate of. Or one that illustrates your list provision, which I don't understand for my second question at all.

Comment: @Gregor Thanks, you were providing as I was typing.

Comment: For the list version, you would want to setup a blank list outside of the for loop using something like `my.list <- list()` then inside of the for loop you can assign each dataframe to the list using `my.list[[paste0(t,"_",d,"_","tcpl.pod")]] <- data.frame(c1,c2,c3,c4,c5))` The save command would then be `save(my.list[[paste0(t,"_",d,"_","tcpl.pod")]] , file = paste0(t,"_",d,"tcpl.pod.RData"))`

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

Comment: It looks like the save method I gave might not work. You can use this to save out each dataframe though `df.to.save <- my.list[[paste0(t,"_",d,"_","tcpl.pod")]]`
`save(df.to.save , file = paste0(t,"_",d,"tcpl.pod.RData"))`

Comment: You're doing it wrong if you're pasting together names of an already-created list. To save each element of the list separately, `lapply(names(my.list), function(x) saveRDS(my.list[[x]], file = paste0(x, ".RDS")))`. Or just save the whole list...

Comment: Gentlemen, I am confused as hell about lists. I still can't get it to name the element of the list using my "tokens".  I want the NAME of the data.frame, whether it is a single item or in a list to be defined with tokens in `paste0( t,"_",d,"tcpl.pod.RData"))`.  I then want to save a .csv and a .RData file by referring to that same token string.  I must be missing something because I can't infer that from either of the links (the duplicate) or the link in first comment.

Comment: It's not clear what code you are running / why you can't generalize because you haven't posted a small, reproducible example. Work up a *simple* example. You don't need `t` and `d`, just pick one variable, let it take 2 values, and create a 2 or 3 row data frame with it. Post the complete code for that example and maybe we can re-open the question and find the problem.